# ORA-00972: identifier is too long ORA-06512

Tags: oracle11g

i have a PROCEDURE like this, whenever i execute the procedure it will give result in cursor according select type:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EMAT_PROC_DROPDOWN_SELECTALL(SELECT_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, RESULT_SET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
  SELECT_TYPE_IN VARCHAR2(100);
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
  FIELD_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
  C_ZONE SYS_REFCURSOR;
  C_USER_ID SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN
  SELECT_TYPE_IN:=SELECT_TYPE;
IF(SELECT_TYPE_IN ='ZONE') THEN
BEGIN
  TABLE_NAME:='MM_ZONEMASTER';
  FIELD_NAME:='ZONE_NAME';
  OPEN C_ZONE FOR
    'SELECT DISTINCT' ||FIELD_NAME|| 'FROM' ||TABLE_NAME||';';
  LOOP
        FETCH C_ZONE INTO RESULT_SET;
        EXIT WHEN C_ZONE%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C_ZONE;
END;
ELSIF(SELECT_TYPE_IN ='USER') THEN
BEGIN
  TABLE_NAME:='AD_USERMASTER';
  FIELD_NAME:='USER_ID';
  OPEN C_USER_ID FOR
   'SELECT DISTINCT' ||FIELD_NAME|| 'FROM' ||TABLE_NAME||';';
  LOOP
    FETCH C_USER_ID INTO RESULT_SET;
        EXIT WHEN C_USER_ID%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C_ZONE;
  END;
  END IF;
END;
```

but the returns the error  ***ORA-00972: identifier is too long
ORA-06512: at "EMAT.EMAT_PROC_DROPDOWN_SELECTALL", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 7

Comment: @JeromeFr  your solution is correct but when i execute                                                                                           BEGIN
  TABLE_NAME:='MM_ZONEMASTER';
  FIELD_NAME:='ZONE_NAME';
  OPEN C_ZONE FOR
    'SELECT DISTINCT ' ||FIELD_NAME|| ' FROM ' ||TABLE_NAME||';';                                                                                                                    ORA-00911: invalid character

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue:  `'SELECT DISTINCT' ||FIELD_NAME|| 'FROM' ||TABLE_NAME||';';`

It will see it as `SELECT DISTINCTZONE_NAMEFROMMM_ZONEMASTER`

The same goes for the other one.

Add spaces and write it as `SELECT DISTINCT ' ||FIELD_NAME|| ' FROM ' ||TABLE_NAME||';';`

Answer (score 0):

There are missing space in the cursor around the field name and the table name. It reads `SELECT DISTINCTZONE_NAMEFROMMM_ZONEMASTER;` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT ZONE_NAME FROM MM_ZONEMASTER;`
Replace that line by this should help :

```
'SELECT DISTINCT ' ||FIELD_NAME|| ' FROM ' ||TABLE_NAME||';';
```

Additionally be careful with the use of nested blocks in your IF. I would avoid abusing from it if it's not needed.